# Update table1 based on value from table 2 in teradata

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, teradata

I have two tables like this

[image]

I would like to insert from Table1 to Table2 here. This is how I want it.

Take MOU = 10. It has num1 and hour1 in the same row.
I would like to insert it into the cell that is at the same row as that of num1 and same column as that of hour1.

How could I do that?

Disclaimer: I am not offering any code here because I am unsure of how to write this query. I sure do know to write a simple update. I am a teracota newbie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked.

```
UPDATE a
FROM table2 a, table1 b
SET hour1=b.mou
WHERE a.access_method_id=b.access_method_id
AND hour='hour1'
```

Did the same for each hours. Not very elegant. But this is all I could get.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some generic SQL that should get the job done.

```
insert into table2(access_method_id, hour1, hour2, ...)
select 
  access_method_id, 
  sum(case when hour='HOUR1' then MOU else 0 end) as hour1,
  sum(case when hour='HOUR2' then MOU else 0 end) as hour2,
  ...etc
from
  table1
group by
  access_method_id
```

Comment: its teracota and so the syntax is pretty different. case is a very good idea. let me try with that. thanks for this

Comment: yes, sorry, i'm not familiar with teradata syntax. hopefully it's easy enough to convert

Comment: no its not :( but case was definitely missing from my mind. i am not that much into db.

Comment: i did some googling and it looks like at least the select portion should be more-or-less equivalent in teradata according to these links: http://readvitamin.com/2007/07/31/%E2%80%98aggregate%E2%80%99-functions-in-teradata-sql/, http://readvitamin.com/2007/07/06/how-to-displaytransform-rows-to-columns-in-teradata/. Those show using SUM, GROUP BY, and CASE statements. I'm not sure what else wouldn't convert easily?

Comment: the update is completely what to say upside down http://aspalliance.com/1784_CodeSnip_How_to_Update_a_Table_by_Selecting_Records_from_another_Table

Answer (score -2):

try this!

```
update table2 t2
from (select 
  access_method_id, 
  sum(case when hour='HOUR1' then MOU else 0 end) as hour1,
  sum(case when hour='HOUR2' then MOU else 0 end) as hour2,
  ...etc
from
  table1) t1
set
t2.hour1=t1.hour1,
t2.hour2=t1.hour2,
t2.hour3=t1.hour3,
...etc
where t2.access_method_id=t1.access_method_id;
```